# Why isn't file explorer search working for partial file names?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I'm using Windows 10. When I search for a file containing "15-47" within a folder in the file explorer, it says no results, but when I look through the folder, I see a file containing 15-47 in the filename (along with some other text -- in case it's relevant, the full file name is ONCA_15-47_ENACTED.pdf). I find that if I enter "ONCA_15-47_ENACTED" instead of "15-47", it does come up as a result. This sort of thing has happened many times in the past. Is there some way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use wildcards in the search field - that is, instead of searching for `15-47`, search for `*15-47*`.

Comment: Thanks, that works! I'm surprised that's not the normal functionality.